CKEditor in Kentico 13
we have hired a developer to help with our Kentico site but they keep telling me it is not possible to copy past text from MS word with Footnoted references into my Kentico site with CKeditor - Kentico suggested adding some coding to help with that task but the answer from the developer is: "we don't think it is worth trying to apply some custom code to the CKEditor. it is never really advised to customize these tools as future builds or hotfixes can break them again and cause disruption across the site, since they are widely used."
so a want for outside experts here: 1) what is up with CKeditor and what else can I do 2)can I used a different editor plug in editor for Kentico 13
we have not been able to cut and past from word with out having to go to html5 editor software before adding it to our Kentico site its a added step that I want to elimiate
